# Flutter Arabic String Containing Html Code UTF8 Decode Problem

Tags: utf-8, flutter, decode

Hey we have a problem with Flutter UTF8 decode method , it can't decode our String that contains Arabic Characters 
here's our code and the String :

```
  **void loadThings() async{
    var str ="<p style=\"text-align: right;\">Â Ø§ÛÙ ÙÛØ±Ù Ø²ÙØ§ÙÛ Ú©Ù ÙÙÙÛ Ø±Ø§ Ø§Ø³ØªÙØ§Ø¯Ù ÙÛÚ©ÙØ¯ Ø¨Ù ÙÙÙ ÙÛØ±Ù ÙØ§Û Ø¯X´ÙÙ ÙØ²Ø¯ÛÚ© Ø´ÙÚ© ÙØ§Ø±Ø¯ ÙÛÚ©ÙØ¯ Ú©Ù Ø¯ÙÛØ¬Û ÙØªØ§ÙØ³Ø¨ Ø¨Ø§ Ø§Ú Ù¾Û ÙÙØ¬ÙØ¯X´Ø§Ù Ø±Ø§ ÙØ§Ø±Ø¯ ÙÛÚ©ÙØ¯.Ø±ÙÛ Ø¯Ø´ÙÙØ§ÙÛ Ú©Ù Ø±ÙÛ Ø¢ÙâÙØ§ ÙÙÙÛ Ø§Ø³ØªÙØ§Ø¯Y Ú©Ø±Ø¯Y Ø¨Ø§Ø´ÛØ¯ ØªØ§Ø«ÛØ± ÙÛâÚ¯Ø°Ø§Ø±Ø¯</p>";
    var ss = utf8.decode(str.codeUnits);
    print(ss);
  }**
```

and here is our error :

> Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86... E/flutter
>   (10047): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error:
>   Unhandled exception: E/flutter (10047): FormatException: Bad UTF-8
>   encoding 0xb4 (at offset 135) E/flutter (10047): #0
>   _Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:568:13) E/flutter (10047): #1      Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:344:13) E/flutter (10047): #2      Utf8Codec.decode (dart:convert/utf.dart:66:60)
>   E/flutter (10047): #3      RetardedWidget.loadThings
>   (package:wog/views/test/retarded_widget.dart:13:19)

Comment: https://mothereff.in/utf-8 also can't decode your string

Comment: You should include information related to *how* you know that the string in question is valid UTF-8 (it's not clear from your snippet).  Until you do, it is unlikely that anyone will answer other then to say: "make sure your string is valid UTF-8; if it still doesn't work come back (with evidence of a valid utf-8 string)"

Comment: Here's another Example with the Exact String , Since i can't find the String Above 
var str ="<p>000000000000000000000Hurls a bolt of lightning that leaps through nearby enemy units.</p>\n\n<p>/-------------------------------/</p>\n\n<p style=\"text-align:right\">یک نیروی الکتریسیته بین نیرو های دشمن پخش میکند</p>\n\n<p>Cast Animation: 0.2+0.63</p>\n\n<p>Cast Range: 850</p>\n\n<p>Bounce Distance: 500</p>\n\n<p>Number Of Bounces: 5 / 7 / 9 / 15</p>\n\n<p>Damage: 70 / 95 / 120 / 145</p>\n\n<p>Mana Cost: 80</p>\n\n<p>Cooldown Time: 1.6</p>\n";